# How can I effectively diff 2 versions of a book produced by ConTeXt?

Tags: context, comparison

I have just made significant revisions to my thesis which has been typeset with ConTeXt. The project file pulls from approximately 20-30 files spread over 8 directories producing a document of 414 pages.

This document is amazingly resistant to normal diffing tools, even if I export the files in an amazingly broken XML export. Is there a `diff` or `wdiff` technique that can produce a list of changes and is intelligent enough to detect when whole sections have been moved around?

Is the "best" way simply to `wdiff` input files and then somehow concatenate those diffs into an output file?

Comment: What can I say...  Are you sure that such a complicated structure is the best possible one?  One possible solution might be to pdf2txt the *resulting* document and diff this one.  This might be a better idea after making a special "mode" to eliminate page numbers, headers etc.

Comment: I've tried that with very poor results. I think the answer is, as you note: "Don't" but I'm hoping to be surprised.

Comment: Although the output here will be typeset with ConTeXt, I don't see how the question relates to TeX. Producing the `diff` is, as described, not done using TeX or a related tool.

Comment: Well, part of it is getting diffable output from context or some (unknown?) aspect of context that could do diffing trivially.

Comment: Moving sections around confuses *any* "diff" tool I know. They are simply not built to do this. The easiest thing would be to have each section in a file of its own, and when you have to reorder them, reorder the `\include` statements in the master document.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way for ConTeXt (or any other TeX macro package or engine) to know you have moved sections around. So unless you added some structure beforehand (by putting things in named buffers or separate input files, for example) the diff output will be large.

The XML export in ConTeXt is indeed using the output order, but comparing the XML output (whether it is good or bad) is not very easy with non-XML tools and besides, it is not quite the input as the link to files and line numbers is lost (same problem with `pdf2txt` export).

My approach to complex changes tracking in large projects is to use a version control system and/or IDE. But if you cannot do that, I assume `pdf2txt` is your least crappy option to get something that `diff` likes, or alternatively use something like `xmldiff` on ConTeXt's XML export.

Comment: Does ConTeXt implement something like the [`changes` package](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/changes/changes.english.pdf) for LaTeX? It would be quite useful to be able to track changes manually in certain cases. I love using ConTeXt for legal documents, I can create more easily than in LaTeX the structures of those documents. Just need to be able to track the changes as it would be in LaTeX with a similar tool, that would be great.